# absolute positioned divs and resizing them

Tags: jquery, css

recently I'm working on a project with background fullsize slideshow, and above the content. Header and footer must have a fixed margin at the top and bottom accordingly.

The middle part should be resizable and have a bit of margin to header and footer.
Most important part - the window should have NO scrollbars and of course all divs should be centered.

The only way I see this working, all three main divs are positoned absolutely.

I'm struggling on resizing the middle part.
I started with @media queries, which work fine since you resize the window vertically and horizontally at the same time (diagonally), but it crashes if you try to resize window vertically (changing heights). I made this by jQuery by changing the CSS properties of each element in a div. This is not very consistent, as I have to change sizes of images. Also, if I rechange back to normal width/height with no refreshment, the css properties defined in JS file are overriden the properties in CSS as they have higher precedence.

Is there any other way to do this?

What would be the best way to resize middle part?

Sorry, here is the code ...

```
    <div class="container">
        <header>

        <div class="nav">
           ---upper navigation part
        </div>

        </header>   

        <div id="content">

            <span class="arrow-left"><a href="#"></a></span>
            <span class="arrow-right"><a href="#"></a></span>
            <div class="central">
            <div class="inner">                                  
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputat</p>
                <div class="contacts">
                <p>some text </p>
                <p>some text </p>
                <div>image div</div>
                </div>

            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <footer>
             <div class="nav">
                 ---- navigation part
             </div>
         </footer>             
    </div>
</body>
```

```
CSS:

.container{
   position: relative;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

header{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    width:1000px;    
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
}
footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    width:1000px;    
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
}

#content{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 113px;
    bottom: 113px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;

}
.central{
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    width:560px;
    float:right;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.inner{
    width:500px;
    float:right;
    padding:0 30px;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.inner h2{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:2em;
    line-height:140%;
}
.inner p{
    line-height:120%;
    font-size:1em;
    padding:15px 0;
}
.image{
    background-image:url(image.png);
    margin-right:0 !important;
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
    width:500px;
    height:232px;
}

AND JS file:
$(window).resize(function(){
    var inner_h = $('.inner').height()/2;
    console.log(inner_h);
    $('.inner').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: '50%',
    'margin-top': '-'+inner_h + 'px'
    });
    $('.inner h2').css({
        'font-size': '2em'
    });
    $('.inner p').css({
        'font-size': '100%'
    });

    if($(window).width() < 1100){
        $('.map').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(images/contact-map350.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });     
    }
    if($(window).height() < 750){
        $('.inner').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: '55%',
            'margin-top': '-'+inner_h + 'px'
        });
        $('.inner h2').css({
            'font-size': '1.5em'
        });
        $('.inner p').css({
            'font-size': '90%'
        });
        $('.image').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(image.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });
    }
    if($(window).height() < 650){

        $('.image').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(image.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });

    }

});
$(window).load(function(){

    var inner_h = $('.inner').height()/2;
    console.log(inner_h);   
    $('.inner').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: '50%',
            'margin-top': '-'+inner_h + 'px'
    });
    $('.inner h2').css({
        'font-size': '2em'
    });
    $('.inner p').css({
        'font-size': '100%'
    });

    if($(window).width() < 1100){
        $('.image').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(image.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });     
    }
    if($(window).height() < 750){

        $('.image').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(image.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });

    }
    if($(window).height() < 650){

        $('.inner').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: '55%',
            'margin-top': '-'+inner_h + 'px'
    });
        $('.image').css({
            'background-size':'350px 162px',
            'background-image':'url(image.png)',
            'width': '350px',
            'height':'162px',
            'float':'left'
        });
    }

    });

// run the function:
$(window).resize();
$(window).load();
```

Comment: Where's the code? https://lkml.org/lkml/2000/8/25/132 ;-)

Comment: This looks like homework at the moment...

Comment: Can you draw up a Paint example of how you would like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your DIVs are absolutely positioned, I think the most dynamic way of resizing this is with straight Javascript or jQuery. Try ditching the media queries and handling everything in the window resize event.

It's difficult to provide an exact answer since you haven't listed any code and I'm not sure where your image is... but a good start is to load an image into a DIV. Then in the JS use new Image() to load your image and place it inside the div. You can then grab the actual image dimensions when loading the image, compare those dimensions to the screen dimensions and resize the image accordingly.